# How to enable P24 Payment method

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

For reference, here is ready  payment  integration form for Stripe Card Payment.

```
import {
  CardCvcElement,
  CardExpiryElement,
  CardNumberElement,
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js"
import {
  StripeCardCvcElementOptions,
  StripeCardExpiryElementOptions,
  StripeCardNumberElementOptions,
} from "@stripe/stripe-js"
import React, { useMemo } from "react"

const PaymentStripe: React.FC = () => {
  const useOptions:
    | StripeCardNumberElementOptions
    | StripeCardExpiryElementOptions
    | StripeCardCvcElementOptions = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      style: {
        base: {
          fontFamily: "Inter, sans-serif",
          color: "#424270",
          padding: "10px 12px",
          "::placeholder": {
            color: "#CFD7E0",
          },
        },
      },
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex flex-col relative w-full pb-6">
        <CardNumber options={useOptions as StripeCardNumberElementOptions} />
        <div className="flex items-center mt-12 relative gap-x-4">
          <CardExpiry options={useOptions as StripeCardExpiryElementOptions} />
          <CardCVC options={useOptions as StripeCardCvcElementOptions} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now I try to enable Przelewy24 payments options.

Can anyone help me, how can I correct import related options to list banks in checkout?

I found in react component:

```
export interface P24BankElementProps extends ElementProps {
  /**
   * An object containing [Element configuration options](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_element?type=p24Bank).
   */
  options?: stripeJs.StripeP24BankElementOptions;

  /**
   * Triggered when data exposed by this Element is changed (e.g., when there is an error).
   * For more information, refer to the [Stripe.js reference](https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/events/on_change?type=p24BankElement).
   */
  onChange?: (event: stripeJs.StripeP24BankElementChangeEvent) => any;

  /**
   * Triggered when the Element is fully rendered and can accept imperative `element.focus()` calls.
   * Called with a reference to the underlying [Element instance](https://stripe.com/docs/js/element).
   */
  onReady?: (element: stripeJs.StripeP24BankElement) => any;

  /**
   * Triggered when the escape key is pressed within the Element.
   */
  onEscape?: () => any;
}
```

So I try import this options, but I get error:

```
import {
    StripeP24BankElement
  } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
  import {
    StripeP24BankElementOptions
  } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
  import React from "react";
  
  const PaymentStripePrzelewy24: React.FC = () => {
  
    const options: StripeP24BankElementOptions = {
      style: {
        base: {
          fontFamily: "Inter, sans-serif",
          color: "#424270",
          padding: "10px 12px",
          "::placeholder": {
            color: "#CFD7E0",
          },
        },
      },
    };
  
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="flex flex-col relative w-full pb-6">
          <StripeP24BankElement options={options} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  export default PaymentStripePrzelewy24;
```

here is error code:

```
error:
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

and second Finally I try add this to second component (payment button):

```
import { useElements, useStripe } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js"
....
...
...
      case "stripe-przelewy24": // Add a case for P24 Bank Element
      return (
        <P24BankPaymentButton notReady={notReady} session={paymentSession} />
      );
...
...
const P24BankPaymentButton: React.FC<{
  session: PaymentSession;
  notReady: boolean;
}> = ({ session, notReady }) => {
  const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);

  const { cart } = useCart();
  const { onPaymentCompleted } = useCheckout();
 
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
  const p24Bank = elements?.getElement(StripeP24BankElement);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!stripe || !elements || !p24Bank || !cart) {
      setSubmitting(true);
    } else {
      setSubmitting(false);
    }
  }, [stripe, elements, p24Bank, cart]);

  const handlePayment = async () => {
    setSubmitting(true);

    if (!stripe || !elements || !p24Bank || !cart) {
      setSubmitting(false);
      return;
    }

   
    await stripe
      .confirmP24Payment(session.data.client_secret as string, {
        payment_method: {
          p24: p24Bank,
          billing_details: {
            name:
              cart.billing_address.first_name +
              " " +
              cart.billing_address.last_name,
            address: {
              city: cart.billing_address.city ?? undefined,
              country: cart.billing_address.country_code ?? undefined,
              line1: cart.billing_address.address_1 ?? undefined,
              line2: cart.billing_address.address_2 ?? undefined,
              postal_code: cart.billing_address.postal_code ?? undefined,
              state: cart.billing_address.province ?? undefined,
            },
            email: cart.email,
            phone: cart.billing_address.phone ?? undefined,
          },
        },
      })
      .then(({ error, paymentIntent }) => {
        if (error) {
          setErrorMessage(error.message);
          return;
        }

        if (paymentIntent && paymentIntent.status === "succeeded") {
          onPaymentCompleted();
        }
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setSubmitting(false);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button disabled={submitting || notReady} onClick={handlePayment}>
        {submitting ? <Spinner /> : "Checkout"}
      </Button>
      {errorMessage && (
        <div className="text-red-500 text-small-regular mt-2">{errorMessage}</div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

But this above code I cant confirm now due to issue with form with list banks, and I  think should be still adjusted to get selected  bank option during confirm payment and should be reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow [Stripe Docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/p24/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=element&client=react) step in step instead. Keep in mind that this is a legacy component, and you should use [Payment Element](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements&client=react) instead, which natively support P24 and bunch of other Payment Methods in once.

Comment: thank you for tip. I fallow to your instruction and  provide update here.